# Access json file in web app folder from gsp grails?

Tags: json, web-applications, grails, gsp

I have a json file called flare.json in the web-app folder of my grails application.

I have a gsp called test.gsp in a folder called reports the views folder.

I have a script in test.gsp that needs to take the json file as input but I can't seem to access it..
I've tried several different ways but have had no luck so far. The example I'm looking at simply uses the following line :

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, data) { .....
```

I have tried the same and several other variations but I keep getting 404 errors saying the resource can't be found. I'm new at grails. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the [g.resource](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html) to create the link for your json file.

```
d3.json('${g.resource(file: "flare.json")}', function(error,data){});
```

Comment: awesome..I had tried that approach earlier but must have had it in the wrong format..Thank you